# How to get the database schema name of a Informatica source definition (oracle table) from the repo views?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am looking for the repo view that has the database schema name of the Source definition. It is listed against "Owner name" field in the Source definition property screen (see attachment).

[Source defnition screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jsdL.png)

For example, I imported a table called schema1.table_name1 in Informatica Powercenter using the Source Analyzer. I need to know which repo view stores the schema name (schema1).

I have already looked at REP_ALL_SOURCES, REP_WIDGET_INST and REP_WIDGET_ATTR but couldn't find it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can check REP_ALL_SOURCES.SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME. If its a shortcut then you need to use parent columns.

Comment: Thanks for responding Joushik. But the SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME is not necessarily the SCHEMA from which you have imported the table. It is more like a group name under which you can group your source tables. Informatica also allows you to rename it to a different name. For example, you can import schema1.table1 as source and then rename it to schema2. Now the SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME will be schema2. But what I am looking for is schema1 (the actual schema from where the table is present in the database).

Comment: hmm, i see, that may be difficult to track. Once someone renames, it changes the name. HOwever it will be in the version. can you do some experiment, like check above column, then change schema and check again ? That is the table which has source info.